# How to access sass variables in a different blazor server project (added as dependency)?

Tags: sass, blazor-server-side

Imagine I have a company, and I'm going to create two blazor server projects: PayrollApp and WarehouseApp.  I want both to look similar.  I'm using sass to compile the css for the projects.  I want to define/maintain "common" sass in *one place* and then **extended it** in each project.  My thought was to create a separate project (as an RCL?) named **CompanyStyles** with scss files like this:

`CompanyStyles/wwwroot/scss/_colors.scss`

The `_colors.scss` file looks like:

```
$primaryColor: red;
$secondaryColor: green;
```

Then I would add this `CompanyStyles` project to the PayrollApp project as a dependency.

In the PayrollApp project I'd have a file like:

`PayrollApp/wwwroot/scss/payrollList.scss`

The `payrollList.scss` file looks like:

```
@use '_content/CompanyStyles/scss/colors'; // this or anything similar won't compile

h1.employee { color: colors.$primaryColor; }
```

When I try to compile `payrollList.scss` of PayrollApp, the dart-sass compiler tells me "Can't find stylesheet to import."

**How can I get access to (aka @use) the *sass variables* (and mixins etc) that's inside the external project CompanyStyles?**. Or if this approach is wrong, how would I have a common base of sass that I only need to maintain once?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with that approach, makes sense to only edit in one place. Seems to me like it's just the file path. I don't know much about blazor, but are you not missing `wwwroot/` from the path in the `@use` rule?

eg.

```scss
@use '_content/CompanyStyles/wwwroot/scss/colors';
```

Comment: Thanks.  The documentation from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio skips the `wwwroot` folder.  (plus I've tried it with and without).  I can consume the RCL in other ways (like referring to compiled css inside the RCL from a PayrollApp .razor page) -- just not in the "raw" scss as a @use.